# Gatsby component shadowing

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am using a gatsby starter [gatsby-theme-carbon](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/gatsby-starter-carbon-theme). It has a switcher component whose code is available [here](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/gatsby-theme-carbon/blob/main/packages/gatsby-theme-carbon/src/components/Switcher/Switcher.js). It looks like this
[Switcher screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtjLM.png).

How do I *disable the Switcher* completely using component shadowing ? ( i.e. I don't want the Switcher at all in my website).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [Shadowing in Gatsby themes docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/plugins-and-themes/shadowing/):

> This feature allows users to replace a file in the `src` directory that
> is included in the webpack bundle with their own implementation. This
> works for React components, pages in `src/pages`, JSON files, TypeScript
> files, as well as any other imported file (such as `.css`) in your site.

The shadowing API uses a deterministic file structure approach to know which component should or shouldn't be rendered. In your case, you just can override the CSS `props` to display it as none, or you just shadow and return an empty component, since shadowing is used to extend Gatsby themes. Create a `src/gatsby-theme-blog/components/Switcher/Switcher.js` in your project and do something like:

```
const Switcher = () => {
  return <></>
};
```

Comment: Hey @Ferran  that did the trick but 98%. Now the drop-down of Switcher (98% of Switcher) vanished but the icon is still there. I feel the icon can be removed if I can remove the `<Switcher />` by shadowing the [Layout.js](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/gatsby-theme-carbon/blob/c6e39f5392ddbd1c46c30b94cfba557e3c825bcc/packages/gatsby-theme-carbon/src/components/Layout.js#L47) component - the component which renders the Switcher itself. But how do I do that ? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I mean how do I remove only `<Switcher />` from [Layout.js](https://github.com/carbon-design-system/gatsby-theme-carbon/blob/c6e39f5392ddbd1c46c30b94cfba557e3c825bcc/packages/gatsby-theme-carbon/src/components/Layout.js#L47) ?

Comment: The approach it's the same. The icon should be in the `Header` component of the theme so to shadow it, you just need to create a `Header.js` in the same folder of your project as it is in the theme `/src/gatsby-theme-blog/components/Header/Header.js` (I guess) and customize your component removing the icon (if it's not the header, apply the same approach to the component that holds the icon you want to remove)